# How can I change the behavior of the commenting function so that the location of the % respect the indentation?

Tags: matlab

When I comment the line 5 using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or clicking on the "comment" icon:

[image]

I get:
[image]

I would like to have instead:
[image]

How to achieve that?

Comment: That's a pretty shoddy implementation (they could have at least not add superfluous indentation). My only suggestion is for you (and other interested users) to go here and click on the *[Request an Enhancement or Report a Bug](http://www.mathworks.com/company/aboutus/contact_us/)* link.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full solution, but a workaround for low levels of indentation.

1. Apply all your comments
2. Use the auto indentation button

The comment will now be at the right place, but unfortunately the space after the comment stays intact. However, for something like the code below you may like it:

```
for t=1:10
%  t
end
```

After removing comments, you can simply use the auto indentation feature again and the code will look proper again.